# Cronjob fails when script is located in other folder

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that has a sentence like this:

```
readarray users < <(cat /etc/passwd | grep 'aText' | awk -F':' '{print $1}');
```

When I run it in my home folder, it works. Same if I run it with sudo. Same success when I run it as a crontab job adding it with `sudo crontab -e` and defined like this: `/15 * * * * /home/my-home/myscript.sh > /home/my-home/myscript.log 2>&1`

When I move the script to the folder `/opt/my-org/my-app/utils/myscript.sh` I can still run it, however when I update the cronjob with `sudo crontab -e` to `/15 * * * * /opt/my-org/my-app/utils/myscript.sh > /opt/my-org/my-app/utils/myscript.log 2>&1` I get the next error in the log file:

```
/opt/my-org/my-app/utils/myscript.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/opt/my-org/my-app/utils/myscript.sh: line 6: `readarray users < <(cat /etc/passwd | grep 'aText' | awk -F':' '{print $1}');'
```

I am using RHEL 7.9

Why is this happening?

My script has the `#!/bin/bash` line, also bash version is 4.3

Also, I noticed this:

```
$ readarray users < <(cat /etc/passwd | grep 'aText' | awk -F':' '{print $1}');
$ echo $?
0

$ sudo readarray users < <(cat /etc/passwd | grep 'aText' | awk -F':' '{print $1}');
sudo: readarray: command not found
$ echo $?
1
```

I am expecting the crontab job to run successfully independently where is it located .

Comment: `readarray -t users < <(awk -F':' '/aText/{print $1}')`; and `sudo bash -c 'readarray ...` but why do you need `sudo` for this? Users don't have permissions for `/etc/passwd` ? Btw, you can't nest same quotes.

Comment: That error message suggests bash is running in sh-compatibility mode, which would indicate that the shebang line isn't working. Changing the script's location shouldn't affect this. Are you sure nothing else changed? BTW, the `sudo readarray` error is normal; `sudo` cannot run shell builtins like `readarray`, it can only run external commands (binaries and scripts).

Comment: @Jetchisel, Thanks for the response. The `sudo` is not needed, you are right. Using awk I still get same error in line 6

Comment: @GordonDavisson, Thanks for the explanation about readarray. 

Yes, nothing else changed in the script, only the location. I am still looking for the reason.